# Does hosting App on multiple domains require multiple AppIDs?

Tags: facebook-apps, app-id, multiple-domains

I have a Silverlight control that's used to author some graphical content, and I am starting work to integrate it to Facebook so people can have access to their pictures. Things are working well, I am using the JavaScript API on the host page of my Silverlight control to interact with Facebook (log in/out, authenticate, etc).

The problem comes when I register my app with Facebook as a web app. This hostpage/Silverlight Control is hosted under several domains. From what I understand, I can register my web app with a domain like www.example.com, and www.example.net, and things will work for similar roots like site.example.com.

But not for www.example2.com. For my application to be able to log in to Facebook under this domain, I would need to register a separate web app with Facebook specifying this second domain, hence having a second Facebook App ID.

Am I understanding correctly? I have a lot of these domains (10+), and will have more in the future. Is there another (better way) to handle this situation?